# using the new keyword in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

Recently started following the flutter [udacity course](https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud905) and while experimenting with creating basic apps I came across something that was unclear to me. When adding widgets, I have noted that doing both `new Widget()` and `Widget()` *[where Widget is any widget being added to the tree]* give the same result. Is there a specific time when you should use `new Widget()` and a time when you should omit the `new` keyword?

For example:

```
return MaterialApp(
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  home: new Scaffold(
    appBar: new AppBar(
      title: Text('My app name')
  ),
)
```

`Text('My app name')` works, but `new Text('My app name')` also works. Any chance I could get some pointers and guidelines on best practices with this?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

`new` was made optional beginning with Dart 2.0, this is why some examples or tutorial still use `new` and newer or updated ones don't.

You can just always omit it.

`const` can be omitted when the context requires `const`

Comment: Ah, thanks for the clarification. Glad to know nothing will break

Comment: Duplicate by the way.

Comment: Didn't know it was not flutter specific @creativecreatorormaybenot, appreciate the clarification

Comment: No prob. This is what the deduplication feature is for.